# Replace all text between 2 strings python

Tags: python

Lets say I have:

```
a = r''' Example
This is a very annoying string
that takes up multiple lines
and h@s a// kind{s} of stupid symbols in it
ok String'''
```

I need a way to do a replace(or just delete) and text in between "This" and "ok" so that when I call it, a now equals:

```
a = "Example String"
```

I can't find any wildcards that seem to work.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need [`Regular Expression`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('\nThis.*?ok','',a, flags=re.DOTALL)
' Example String'
```

Comment: Some elaboration on what is happening would have helped more.

Answer (score 10):

Another method is to use string splits:

```
def replaceTextBetween(originalText, delimeterA, delimterB, replacementText):
    leadingText = originalText.split(delimeterA)[0]
    trailingText = originalText.split(delimterB)[1]

    return leadingText + delimeterA + replacementText + delimterB + trailingText
```

Limitations:

- Does not check if the delimiters exist
- Assumes that there are no duplicate delimiters
- Assumes that delimiters are in correct order

Answer (score 8):

Use `re.sub` : It replaces the text between two ***characters** or **symbols** or **strings*** with desired **character** or **symbol** or **string**.

```
format: re.sub('A?(.*?)B', P, Q, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

```
where 
A : character or symbol or string
B : character or symbol or string
P : character or symbol or string which replaces the text between A and B
Q : input string
re.DOTALL : to match across all lines
```

```
import re
re.sub('\nThis?(.*?)ok', '', a,  flags=re.DOTALL)

output : ' Example String'
```

Lets see an example with html code as input

```
input_string = '''<body> <h1>Heading</h1> <p>Paragraph</p><b>bold text</b></body>'''
```

**Target** : remove `<p>` tag

```
re.sub('<p>?(.*?)</p>', '', input_string,  flags=re.DOTALL)

output : '<body> <h1>Heading</h1> <b>bold text</b></body>'
```

**Target** : replace `<p>` tag with word : `test`

```
re.sub('<p>?(.*?)</p>', 'test', input_string,  flags=re.DOTALL)

otput : '<body> <h1>Heading</h1> test<b>bold text</b></body>'
```

Answer (score 5):

The DOTALL flag is the key. Ordinarily, the '.' character doesn't match newlines, so you don't match across lines in a string. If you set the DOTALL flag, re will match '.*' across as many lines as it needs to.

Answer (score 4):

```
a=re.sub('This.*ok','',a,flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want first and last words:

```
re.sub(r'^\s*(\w+).*?(\w+)$', r'\1 \2', a, flags=re.DOTALL)
```