# PYTHON - find substring "(DefinedBeginOfTheString)(anySubstring, it doesnt matter)(DefinedEndOfTheString)"

Tags: python, string

I have a long .txt file containing list of parameters in some given format. Let's say it look like this:

```
oneParameter = "definedStartSequenceOfTheParameter" + str(actualValueOfTheParameter) + "definedEndSequenceOfTheParameter"
```

My problem is that I would like to replace the value `actualValueOfTheParameter`. But I cannot use `.replace` method since I never actually know the value of `actualValueOfTheParameter` - it can be string, 10 digit float or 2 digit int, any value you can think of.

This brought me to a question whether there is perhaps some way to tell Python something like this:

find string which starts with `"definedStartSequenceOfTheParameter"` and ends with `"definedEndSequenceOfTheParameter"` while it does not matter how many or which characters are in between starting and ending string.

I know I could define some function containing `for` cycle but first I would like to have your opinion. So I don't shoot myself in the leg in case there exist some simple method or escape sequence that I do not know about.

Comment: Do you want the text in between if so let me know I believe I can help you

Comment: The really interesting part, which none of the existing answers mention: may the given end sequence also be part of the actual value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace all text between 2 strings python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159969/replace-all-text-between-2-strings-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regex `sub()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub

```
s = "knownbeginKJLKYLHLKHDLLKDLBKBDKBknownend"
re.sub(r"(knownbegin).+(knownend)", r"\1" + replacenment + r"\2", s)
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on C14L answer, use regex. Simple tool is to build a good regex is [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Here's a simple solution, I think you can figure out how to read text from a file on your own.

```
import re

testString = "definedStartSequenceOfTheParameterTheSpecificParameterdefinedEndSequenceOfTheParameter"

m = re.search('(?<=definedStartSequenceOfTheParameter)(.*)(?=definedEndSequenceOfTheParameter)',testString)
print(m.group(0))
```

Output:

```
TheSpecificParameter
```

Comment: Thanks, I am unable to mark more answers as correct, but this would also work.

Answer (score -1):

You could try the `str.startswith()` and `str.endswith()` methods.

Example:

```
string = "Hello"
if string.startswith("H") and string.endswith("o"):
    print("Yay!")
else:
    print("Nay!")
```

Comment: Yeah, but in the question he asks:

Comment: find string which starts with "definedStartSequenceOfTheParameter" and ends with "definedEndSequenceOfTheParameter" while it does not matter how many or which characters are in between starting and ending string.

Comment: He never asked for the text in between.

Comment: You simplify the problem to a degree, where the similarity to the question is lost. Your code shows no simple enhancement path towards an extraction.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your quick response. This would for sure work given the poor explanation I provided. However in the actual application I could not use this - but you had no way knowing and this really is the most simple way (after all such a rookie as me is also came up with this solution but was left stone faced when it did not work). Thank you though!

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your project!