# SQL equivalent of 'like' operator in Python?

Tags: python, string

Beginner here again. I've checked out the other similar question on stackoverflow but the response is too confusing. This here is the original question given by our Python instructor at college:

> Your course instructor asked you to write programming which takes the input as a string from the user. Now your task is to find the first appearance of the substring 'not' and 'poor' from a given string, if 'not' follows the 'poor', replace the whole 'not'...'poor' substring with 'good'. Return the resulting string.

> E.g.,
> String: 'The lyrics is not that poor!'
> Result: 'The lyrics is good!'

> String: 'The lyrics is poor!'
> Result: 'The lyrics is poor!'

What I understand from the question is that we have to find and replace the part of the string starting from 'not' to 'poor', so I had the idea of using something similar to the "LIKE" operator in MySQL. But I cannot find any alternatives. Please help.

Comment: you can use regex which would be the `re` module or you can iterate over each word in the sentence and keep track of indexes to see if both words are in the sentence, if they are you can use those indexes to slice the sentence and replace it with the desired word.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace all text between 2 strings python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159969/replace-all-text-between-2-strings-python)

Comment: @Tomerikoo it should, but the explanation is too mind-wrecking for a beginner like me, sorry.

Comment: @gold_cy right, i have to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.sub` we can try:

```py
inp = ['The lyrics is not that poor!', 'The lyrics is poor!']
output = [re.sub(r'\bnot\b.*\bpoor\b', 'good', x) for x in inp]
print(output)  # ['The lyrics is good!', 'The lyrics is poor!']
```

Comment: Yes, but what logic is being used here? what is `r'` here? and what is `\b` doing here?

Comment: `r''` is a raw string, and `\b` is a word boundary.